# How to get an average from a table that was originated by other 2 tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This post will be up again by the 1st of February 2016.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` with `AVG()`.

Comment: Why do you have duplicate rows in `user_login_attempts`?

Comment: It is supose to have different 'moment' entries. I've changed it. Thanks for the heads up ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   Select AVG(subquery.tries) from (SELECT DISTINCT la.userid, la.tries AS "tries", u.country, u.category
    FROM user_login_attempts la, user_country u
    WHERE tl.userid = u.userid
    AND u.country = 'Portugal')subquery ;
```

also read this: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/subqueries.php